# Gwt - separate code between tab in TabPanel

Tags: java, gwt

I have a big application written in GWT. I one case a have 10 tabs in TabPanel. unfortunately there is only one view with .xml and presenter. Both of them have more than 5 lines of code :(

How can I separate this code beetwen tabs.

I imagine there could be like that:

One .xml file, view, presenter for TabPanel definition

```
<g:TabPanel ui:field="tabPanel" addStyleNames="{style.versionTabs}">
    <g:Tab text="1">
        <g:FlowPanel>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:Tab>
    <g:Tab text="2">
        <g:FlowPanel>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:Tab>
</g:TabPanel>
```

And one .xml file, view and presenter for each tabs.

But how can I configure it? In EntryPoint?

Comment: This question isn't overly clear. But there is nothing to stop you defining your own `Composite` for each tab and using that in your `UIBinder` rather than the `FlowPanel`. If fact, this is exactly the sort of thing custom widgets are for.

Comment: How to use UIBinder instead of FlowPanel?

Comment: That is GWT 101. Create a custom widget. Use what ever you want in that widget, `UIBinder` or not doesn't matter. Then include it in the parent widget as you would include any other widget.